# How do you do a selection sort in MASM Assembly?

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

So I'm trying to sort an array in ascending order, and it just doesn't seem to work for me. I know my swap procedure is wrong, and my minIndex procedure only works half the time, but the randomly filled array generates just fine.

**Working Code Thanks to vitsoft:**

```
include Irvine32.inc

; Constants
    NUM_INTEGERS = 20
    NUM_RANGE = 99d
    TO_ENSURE_NOT_ZERO = 1d

.data
; Declare Arrays
; Declare Array of 20 Integers
    array byte NUM_INTEGERS dup(?)

; Displayed Annotation for Unsorted Array
    unsortedArrayText byte "Randomly Generated Array, Unsorted: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0

; Displayed Annotation for Sorted Array
    sortedArrayText byte "Randomly Generated Array, Sorted from Lowest to Highest: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0

.code
main PROC
; Get Random Values for Array
    call fillArrayRandomly

; Display Array with Annotation
    mov edx, offset unsortedArrayText
    call WriteString

    mov ecx, offset array
    push ecx
    call displayArray

; Sort Array
    mov esi, offset array
    mov ecx, NUM_INTEGERS
    call findMinimum

    mov edi, offset array
    mov ecx, NUM_INTEGERS
    call selectionSort

; Display Sorted Array with Annotation
    mov edx, offset sortedArrayText
    call WriteString

    mov ecx, offset array
    push ecx
    call displayArray

; Exit Program
    exit
main endp

; Fill Array with Random Values
fillArrayRandomly PROC
; Set Counter to NUM_INTEGERS and Index to 0
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, NUM_INTEGERS
    mov esi, 0

getRandomNumber:
; Fill Array with Random Numbers and Increment ESI for Offset
    mov ah, NUM_RANGE
    call RandomRange
    add ah, TO_ENSURE_NOT_ZERO

testUniqueness:
    mov al, array [esi]
    cmp al, ah
    jne uniqueNumber
    loop getRandomNumber

uniqueNumber:
    mov array [esi], ah
    inc esi
    loop getRandomNumber

    ret
fillArrayRandomly ENDP

; Display Array
displayArray PROC
    pushad
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, NUM_INTEGERS
    mov esi, 0

display:
    mov al, array[esi]
    call WriteDec
    mov al, TAB
    call WriteChar
    inc esi
    loop display

    popad
    call Crlf
    ret
displayArray ENDP

; Selection Sort
selectionSort PROC
    dec ecx
    mov ebx, edi
    mov edx, ecx

startOuterLoop:
    mov edi, ebx
    mov esi, edi
    inc esi
    push ecx
    mov ecx, edx

startInnerLoop:
    mov al, [esi]
    cmp al, [edi]
    pushf
    inc esi
    inc edi
    popf
    jae doNotSwap
    call swap

doNotSwap:
    loop startInnerLoop
    pop ecx
    loop startOuterLoop

    ret
selectionSort ENDP

; Find Minimum Index
findMinimum PROC
    mov edi, esi

minimumIndex:
    mov al, [esi]
    cmp al, [edi]
    jae skip
    mov edi, esi

skip: 
    inc esi
    loop minimumIndex

    ret
findMinimum ENDP

; Swap
swap PROC
    mov al, [esi - 1]
    mov ah, [edi - 1]
    mov [esi - 1], ah
    mov [edi - 1], al

    ret
swap ENDP

END main
```

Comment: After the inner **loop sortTheRest** is finished, ECX=0 and the following
**loop selectionSort** will jump to **selectionSort** 4294967295 times,
pushing 32 bytes on stack each time. You'd better loop to a new label just below **pushad** and don't forget to reinitialize loop counter ECX before entering the inner loop.

Comment: @vitsoft Thank you, added startHere label after pushad and set ECX to NUM_INTEGERS after call minimumIndex. However, when I ran the program, it takes an excruciatingly amount of time to sort. It generated the array within ten seconds but it's been almost two minutes and I haven't seen the sorted array or annotation...

Comment: Yeah it doesn't ever sort now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.data
unsortedArrayText DB "Randomly Generated Array, Unsorted: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
sortedArrayText   DB "Randomly Generated Array, Sorted from Lowest to Highest: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0 
array             DB "An array of bytes (characters) which will be sorted"
NewLine           DB 0dh, 0ah, 0
NUM_INTEGERS      EQU NewLine - array ; Number of integers (characters) in array  
.code

main PROC
; Display Array with Annotation
; mov edx, offset unsortedArrayText
; call WriteString
ConsoleWrite unsortedArrayText
  ; push offset array
  ; call displayArray
ConsoleWrite array

; Sort Array
  ;   push offset array
  ;   call selectionSort
MOV EDI,array
MOV ECX,NUM_INTEGERS
CALL selectionSort

; Display Sorted Array with Annotation
   ; mov edx, offset sortedArrayText
   ; call WriteString
ConsoleWrite sortedArrayText
   ; push offset array
   ; call displayArray
ConsoleWrite array
; Exit Program
    ;exit
 TerminateProgram
main endp

; Selection Sort
selectionSort PROC ; Bubble sort ECX byte array pointed to with EDI
    DEC ECX        ; Number of compare is NUM_INTEGERS-1
    MOV EBX,EDI    ; Save array pointer to EBX
    MOV EDX,ECX    ; Save number of compare to EDX
OuterLoop:
    MOV EDI,EBX    ; Restore array pointer     
    LEA ESI,[EDI+1] ; Neibourghing field
    PUSH ECX        ; Save OuterLoop counter on stack
     MOV ECX,EDX     ; Initialize InnerLoop counter
InnerLoop:    
     CMPSB ; compare the first byte [EDI] with its neibourgh [ESI], advance EDI,ESI
     JAE NoSwap
     CALL swap
NoSwap:
     LOOP InnerLoop
    POP ECX     ; Restore OuterLoop counter
    LOOP OuterLoop
    RET
selectionSort ENDP

swap PROC ; Swap bytes at [EDI-1] and [ESI-1]
     MOV AL,[ESI-1]
     MOV AH,[EDI-1]
     MOV [ESI-1],AH
     MOV [EDI-1],AL
     RET
swap ENDP
```

This worked well, statically defined array was sorted in few miliseconds:

```
C:\ASM>bubblesortexample.exe
Randomly Generated Array, Unsorted:
An array of bytes (characters) which will be sorted
Randomly Generated Array, Sorted from Lowest to Highest:
        ()Aaaaabbcccdeeeefhhhiillnoorrrrrssstttwwyy
C:\ASM>
```

Comment: Tried inputting it into my code, it wouldn't allow `mov edi, array` because the operands weren't the same size...

Comment: Oh! I figured it out, I'm dumb. Had to do the offset of the array. Thanks so much!

Comment: I just have a couple questions: is there another way to implement both `lea esi, [edi + 1]` and `cmpsb`? Haven't learned those in class yet. In addition, I unfortunately need a minimum index procedure, in this procedure, where would I call it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

LOAD EFFECTIVE ADDRESS computes address of 2nd operand and moves it to the first operand.

**lea esi,[edi+1]** can be replaced with

```
mov esi,edi
inc esi
```

if you don't mind that INC will also change ZERO flag.

You should learn **cmpsb** and other string instructions ASAP, they are very useful.

**cmpsb** can be replaced with

```
MOV AL,[ESI]
CMP AL,[EDI]
PUSHF
 INC ESI
 INC EDI 
POPF
```

After **selectionSort** has been called, the minimal value will be in the first field of your array.
Nevertheless, if your assignment was to find a pointer to the minimal value of array, here you are:

```
findMinimum PROC ; Return EDI=offset of leftmost byte in array with minimal value
; Input: ESI is offset of an byte array,  ECX is the size of array
      MOV EDI,ESI  ; Initialize pointer with so far minimal value
 next:MOV AL,[ESI] ; Load next value
      CMP AL,[EDI] ; Compare with minimal value so far 
      JAE skip
      MOV EDI,ESI  ; Value loaded from [ESI] was below, so ESI is better candidate
 skip:INC ESI      ; Advance offset in array
      LOOP next
      RET
findMinimum ENDP
```